# Pasting images from clipboard in Safari

Tags: safari, google-chrome, copy-paste, facebook

On Windows (Chrome, Firefox) I was used to copying a picture to the clipboard and to paste it for example into the message composition section of facebook or vkontakte. On Mac OS X this does not seem to work, neither in Safari nor in Chrome. In order to send a screenshot as message, I now need to take the screenshot, save it and navigate to the corresponding location in the file open dialog.

[image]

Is there a workaround, third-party program or setting to manage this on a Mac?

Comment: I drag-and-drop from Firefox to other apps on Lion. Click and start dragging, then you can Cmd-tab to other app, Fn-11 to see desktop and drop or even Ctrl-[ desktop # ] to change to a different desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari 10.1 was released today and fixes this issue. Just update MacOS from the AppStore.

Comment: This is not working for me on 10.1.2. What version are you running?

Comment: Not working for me in 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7) (neither Facebook or Whatsapp   Web)

Comment: Almost 2018 now, weird we can't paste images yet ... Version 11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6)

Answer (score 1):

I know you can copy images in Firefox, as far as Chrome goes I haven't used it in years. With Safari however if you are talking about still images you should be able to Command-C an image. If that doesn't work you could always "Copy Image Location"/"Copy Image Address" in either Firefox or Safari, then open Preview and choose to open the URL you just copied. From there you can use the normal Select/Command-C/Command-V to paste whatever section of the image you'd like into any other system app that displays images (i.e. iMessage via the attach feature). That would at least eliminate the need for using Grab, however if you are okay with it you could also simply save the image itself temporarily, click the Attachment button, drag and drop the image from your downloads fan/folder and delete it when you're done.

Comment: It's not about copying them, just pasting them back inside the browser.